Is fusing shuffle(tbl)+cvt+add is possible for the same throught as MAD (multiply-add) SIMD instrcution on AVX or NEON?
I ran a benchmark on my core i5 (Rapoter Lake) for _mm256_shuffle_epi8 and _mm256_maddubs_epi16, and they have nearly the same Throughput just like the AVX documentation said.
In fact, for now there is a trend that using LUT(lookup table) to compute GEMV on edge. For AVX, it needs _mm256_shuffle_epi8 + _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 + _mm256_add_epi8 to finish.
For example:
        __m256i res = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(c, _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(res)));

However, these instrcutions are too complex compared to _mm256_maddubs_epi16, which fuse the mul+cvt+add in one execution unit. So that LUT Throughput is about 30% lower than _mm256_maddubs_epi16.
I'm looking for some evidences that shows if we fuse the _mm256_shuffle_epi8 + _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 + _mm256_add_epi8 so that the Throughput for LUT can also meets the _mm256_maddubs_epi16. There are papers like LUTMUL which makes a FPGA version but it seems not that clear.
Many Thanks for the help.

Welcome to SO! Can you please post some actually compiling code (ideally a function with a complete inner loop). E.g., _mm256_shuffle_epi8 needs two inputs. I could only speculate where your inputs may come from (inter-loop dependencies are very relevant for any statement about throughput). Also, links to external references are fine, but the question should be self-contained to understand your problem.

_mm256_castsi256_si128(_mm256_shuffle_epi8(src, lut)) is equivalent to _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm256_castsi256_si128(src), _mm256_castsi256_si128(lut)), i.e., it completely ignores the upper halves of src and lut -- AVX2 has no cross-lane shuffle with byte-granularity. Please clarify what you actually want to do.

Also, also: How is your problem related to [neon]?

If you were designing your own ISA, you could have an instruction that did everything in one step, since you say you've found a paper about how to build an efficient execution-unit for it.  But AVX2 doesn't have that. The instruction decoders only fuse FLAG-setting with jcc conditional branches into a single uop, not multiple vector ALU instructions.  Often a vpmaddwd multiply is a useful first step in a horizontal add even with trivial constant multipliers like 1, despite wasting a bit of power making all those gates in a multiply unit flip.

More recent ISA extensions like AMX have 8-bit integer matmul and dot-product, e.g. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-9/tile-dpbssd.html
